# Op-Amp tester on LM4250

Tags: operational-amplifier, tester

So I have found this Op-Amp tester on Google [here link](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/bitmaps/opamp-tester-schematic.png) and while it works on a 741 it doesn't on my [LM4250](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4250.pdf) (*Programmable operational amplifier*). Is this supposed to work on any op-amp or have I just fried another 4250? I've read that it is a programmable op-amp, I don't know if it means anything or not.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Provide a link to the LM4250 datasheet.

Comment: Yes, a programmable op-amp generally means something different to a "standard" opamp - the exact details will be in the datasheet though, which we don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the datasheet for the LM4250 that I found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4250.pdf) the LM4250 seems to have the same pinout as the LM741 with the exception of pin 8, which is the "Quiescent Current Set" for the LM4250 and "NC" for the LM741. To quote the datasheet, the op amp uses:

> A single external master bias current setting resistor programs the input bias current, input offset current, quiescent power consumption, slew rate, input noise, and the gain-bandwidth product.

So it's my understanding that pin 8 is used to adjust the quiescent current through the differential pair and output stage of the op amp. Looking at [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa652a/snoa652a.pdf) application report for the LM4250, it seems like it requires at least a resistor connected from pin 8 to ground or V- to be operational, but there are multiple other biasing methods shown on page 5 & 6. Thus if pin 8 is left floating, the biasing current for the internal differential pair will not be set properly.

Moving forward, looking at Figure 10 on page 9 of [the application report](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa652a/snoa652a.pdf) I mentioned previously, using a resistor upwards of 12MOhms connected from pin 8 to ground (you may need to pick a different value based on your needs) should provide a good enough bias current for testing the op amp.

I personally do not have much experience with programmable op amps but if anyone does, please correct me if I've provided any wrong information.